# Color coding each row in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, colors

Let me start by saying that I am new to `MVVM`, so please bare with be, if the question is unclear let me know and I will try to clarify.

I have a button which is successfully binding a ListView. (it populates the listView).
below is the button VM code:

```
<Button Content="Fetch Data" Command="{Binding readFilesCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=browseFolderTextBox}" Name="button1" />
```

The listView which is being populated looks like this:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Extended" Name="responseListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="responseListViewClick" >
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:IndexConverter x:Key="IndexConverter" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="OrdinalColumnDataTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem},
                Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IndexConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gridView2" AllowsColumnReorder="True">
            <GridViewColumn Width="28" Header="#" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OrdinalColumnDataTemplate}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EMail}" Header="EMail" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" Header="Date" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" Header="Time" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Below is the code of the class being populated in the listView.

```
public class ResourceList : ObservableCollection<Resource>
{
    public ResourceList() : base()
    {
    }
}

public class Resource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Resource()
    {
        Name = "";
        EMail = "";
        Date = "";
        Time = "";
        SWList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    private string name;
    private string eMail;
    private string time;
    private string date;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name;}
        set 
        {
            if(name != value) 
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public string EMail
    {
        get { return eMail; }
        set 
        {
            if (eMail != value) 
            {
                eMail = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EMail");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Date
    {
        get { return date;}
        set 
        {
            if (date != value) 
            {
                date = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Date");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Time
    {
        get { return time; }
        set 
        {
            if (time != value) 
            {
                time = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Time");
            }
        }
    }

    // This interface causes the View to be notified of changes to the instances of Resource.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> SWList { get; set; }
}

// ObservableCollection notifies the View of changes to the collection (add, delete, move items)
public class Licenses : ObservableCollection<Licenses>
{
    public Licenses()
    {
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string License { get; set; }
}
```

so far everything works fine. Now on to my question. I would like each row of the ListView to have a background color. lets say property time is missing for one row, then I would like the whole row to be red. Where should I start?

Comment: WPF ? Silverlight ? WinRT ?

Answer (score 0):

You can surround each `ListViewItem` with a container (do that with a template) and change the background color of this container with a binding or a DataTrigger.

One example here : [Change background color of GridView row in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999691/change-background-color-of-gridview-row-in-a-listview)

**EDIT :** according to MVVM, you should define a business property on your class `Resource`, of a type such `boolean` (IsValid ?) or enum (Status ?), and use a converter inside your Binding to convert the value to a `SolidColorBrush` (for example).